# Temp tables are created by default in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have created a database "MyDB.sqlite" using the command line `sqlite3 MyDB.sqlite` in a specific folder(my desktop) and then created a table "tbl11" using create table syntax. I am able to insert record and can check the inserted records.

But when I exit command (terminal in Mac) line and re enter I can't see my database and tables in that folder. I guess this database and table are temporary by default. I even check the `.databases` command to see the database, but I can only see two database main!

please help!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to finish off with `COMMIT;`  :-)

For practice, work through the short working example at http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html

Good luck.

Comment: SQLite runs in autocommit mode by default; you don't need COMMIT if you didn't BEGIN a transaction in the first place.